# Add a value from another column based on the last negative value found for the current row

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following Dataframe:

```
data = {'Column A':[400, 522, 633, 744, 150, 140, 119, 744, 150, 400, 390, 315, 744, 150, 400, 522, 500, 633, 744, 204, 215, 150],
    'Column B':[400, 0, 0, 0, -150, 0, 0, 744, 0, -400, 0, 0, -744, 0, -400, 0, 0, -633, 0, 0, 0, 150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I want to do is tell the program to go row by row and compare the absolute value of the last negative value in Column B with the Column A value for the current row and if it is 20% lower copy it to Column B. This is how the Dataframe with the modified column B would look like:

```
data = {'Column A':[400, 522, 633, 744, 150, 140, 119, 744, 150, 400, 390, 315, 744, 150, 400, 522, 500, 633, 744, 204, 215, 150],
    'Column B':[400, 0, 0, 0, -150, 0, 119, 744, 0, -400, 0, 315, -744, 150, -400, 0, 0, -633, 0, 204, 215, 150],
    }
```

So for example in the 6th row the last negative value in column B is -150 so its absolute will be 150 when you compare this value with the value of 140 in column A, then the value is not copied since 140 is still inside the 20% threshold, however in the 7th row 119 is more than 20% lower than 150 so is copied to column B. On the 10th row the last negative becomes -400 so it will begin using this value to compare, then again skips 390 but copies 315.

I hope it's clear enough and thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

```
last_value = 0
for i, n in df.iterrows():
   if n["Column B"] < 0:
       last_value = abs(n["Column B"])
   if n["Column A"] < last_value*0.8:
       df.loc[df.index == i, 'Column B'] = n["Column A"]
```

Comment: This solves the problem but since my original dataset has thousands of rows isn't there a more efficient way without using If statements or for loops?

Comment: ..to be honest, I have no option in mind by not using conditional statements and a loop to at least, iterate your dataframe...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['New Column B'] = np.where(df['Column B'].ge(0), np.nan, df['Column B'])
df['New Column B'].ffill(inplace=True)
condition = df['Column A'] < abs(df['New Column B']*0.8))
df['New Column B'].mask(condition, df['Column A'], inplace=True)
condition = df['Column B'].ne(df['New Column B']) & df['New Column B'].ne(df['Column A'])
df['New Column B'].mask(condition, df['Column B'], inplace=True)
df['New Column B'] = df['New Column B'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Muhammad thank you for this your solution is way more efficient however since I need to replace 'Column B' with 'New Column B' I wanted to ask you if during the process there is a way to avoid using an auxiliary column like 'New column B'  and simply overwrite Column B on the spot so that 'New Column B'  becomes the actual column B with the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner with `np.where` and after `ffill` the last negative value in the column B.

```
df['newColB'] = ( # you can reassign directly to Column B
    np.where(df['Column A']<0.8*df['Column B'].where(df['Column B']<0).ffill().abs(), 
             df['Column A'], df['Column B'])
)
print(df)
    Column A  Column B  New Column B  newColB
0        400       400           400      400
1        522         0             0        0
2        633         0             0        0
3        744         0             0        0
4        150      -150          -150     -150
5        140         0             0        0
6        119         0           119      119
7        744       744           744      744
8        150         0             0        0
9        400      -400          -400     -400
10       390         0             0        0
11       315         0           315      315
12       744      -744          -744     -744
13       150         0           150      150
14       400      -400          -400     -400
15       522         0             0        0
16       500         0             0        0
17       633      -633          -633     -633
...
```